# RGB to xyY color space conversion and luminance

Tags: opengl, mathematics, graphics, glsl

The luminance calculated by following GLSL functions ([fragment shaders - tonemap](http://www.nutty.ca/?page_id=352&link=hdr)) has different value:

```
float GetLuminance (vec3 rgb)
{
     return (0.2126 * rgb.x) + (0.7152 * rgb.y) + (0.0722 * rgb.z);
}


vec3 RGB2xyY (vec3 rgb)
{
     const mat3 RGB2XYZ = mat3(0.4124, 0.3576, 0.1805,
                               0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722,
                               0.0193, 0.1192, 0.9505);
    vec3 XYZ = RGB2XYZ * rgb;

    return vec3(XYZ.x / (XYZ.x + XYZ.y + XYZ.z),
                XYZ.y / (XYZ.x + XYZ.y + XYZ.z),
                XYZ.y);
}
```

I used a glm library to calculate an example result. For glm::vec3(2.0f, 3.0f, 8.0f) GetLuminance returns 3.1484. RGB2xyY returns glm::vec3 which z component is equal 3.8144. What is wrong ?

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with your implementation, but here's [another one](http://www.f4.fhtw-berlin.de/~barthel/ImageJ/ColorInspector/HTMLHelp/farbraumJava.htm) you can try.

Comment: I think that both luminances should have the same value.

Comment: I understand that something *is* wrong, I just don't know where the problem lays. So I was giving you another implementation should you could implement and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Well what is the answer you should be getting?  That should tell you which one is "wrong"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either the matrix is transposed (i.e. rows and columns swapped) in `RGB2xyY`, or the equation in `GetLuminance` uses the row vector instead of the column vector. The two values just happen to be close by accident.

Here is a Matlab trace showing whats going on. The quote is used to indicate matrix transposition. (The multiplication below is swapped around, of course you could also do `s*v'` and `s'*v'`).

BTW, using tools like Matlab (or Octave) are great for quickly prototyping these types of algorithms and finding bugs like these fast.

```
>> s = [0.4124, 0.3576, 0.1805;
        0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722;
        0.0193, 0.1192, 0.9505] %assign matrix to s

s =

    0.4124    0.3576    0.1805
    0.2126    0.7152    0.0722
    0.0193    0.1192    0.9505

>> v = [2 3 8] % assign vector to v

v =

     2     3     8

>> v*s         % multiply

ans =

    1.6170    3.8144    8.1816

>> v*s'        % multiply with transposed matrix

ans =

    3.3416    3.1484    8.0002
```